# Заливка текста видеороликом

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

Не получается изменить задний фон текста на другие цвета , кроме белого - добавляется прозрачность.

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-reduced-motion)').matches) {
  video.removeAttribute("autoplay");
  video.pause();
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Biko;
  src:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/biko-black.woff");
}
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 2rem;
}
header { 
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
header video { width: 100%; }
svg { 
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; // needed for FF, Safari, Edge
  height: 100%;
}
svg text {
  font-family: Biko, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 38px;
}
svg rect {
  fill: white;
}
svg > rect {
    -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
    mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<header>
 <video autoplay playsinline muted loop preload poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/oceanshot.jpg">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/ocean-small.webm" />
    <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/ocean-small.mp4" />
 </video>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 285 80" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" >
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <text x="72"  y="50">OCEAN</text>
      </mask>
  </defs>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </svg>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас всё работает, вот только строчные комментарии в css писать нельзя, они поломали одно важное свойство.

Вот это удалите: `// needed for FF, Safari, Edge`

Или замените на: `/*needed for FF, Safari, Edge*/`

Comment: Заработало, спасибо)